# No entry for terminal type when SSHing into a router?

Tags: linux, macos, networking, ssh, terminal

I’m trying to SSH/Telnet to my home router ([Zyxel P-2812HNU-F1](ftp://ftp.zyxel.com/P-2812HNU-F3/P-2812HNU-F3_1.0.pdf)).

I know the router host and IP address. Also the administrator login credentials.

I’ve set ssh to port `2222` and telnet to `2323`.

When I SSH via Mac OS X Terminal it connects but the terminal says:

```
No entry for terminal type `vt220`; using dumb terminal settings.
 ZySH>
```

When I type for instance "?" it shows the following:

```
No entry for terminal type "vt100";
using dumb terminal settings.
ZySH>
clear                                 - Reset functions
configure                             - Enter configuration mode
copy                                  - Copy from one file to another
disable                               - Exit privileged EXEC mode
exit                                  - Close an active terminal session
history                               - Display or clear CLI history
reboot                                - Shutdown and perform a cold restart
release                               - Perform an immediate release of a Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (D
                                        HCP) lease for an interface
renew                                 - Perform an immediate renewal of a Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (D
                                        HCP) lease for an interface
show                                  - Show running system information
traffic-mirror                        - <N/A>

ZySH>
```

it does the same for the following terminal types:
-linux
-vt100
-vt102
-xterm
-xterm-256color

**What am I dealing with and what are the possibilities of fixing this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message only means your router does not know the terminal type you are using. The list of terminal types known to a *Nix system is kept in `/usr/share/terminfo`, there are several hundred.

You can try to fix your small problem by trying them all and see whether your router was actually configured with a specific terminal in mind, since the instructions you linked to above shed no light on this.

The following one-liner will do it:

```
find /usr/share/terminfo -type f -exec sh -c 'echo basename {} && TERM=$(basename {}) ssh me@remote echo $TERM' \;
```

This will first search for all terminal types known to your system (in /usr/share/terminfo; if the list is elsewhere, like termcap, pls adjust accordingly), then will print the term type just found and try to ssh into your router (me@remote) by using as TERM type the term type just found, and will execute `echo $TERM` on the remote system. When you find a line in which the two outputs match, you will have found the termcap capability of your router.

This of course works best if you have setup passwordless login on the remote system.

Comment: Nice, I will try it out. Thank you very much!

Comment: is there a way to also include my password into that one-liner?  Because now it consecutively asks for my password.

Comment: @MieerDarwesh Yes there is,  it is called sshpass, readhere http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118308/command-line-to-execute-ssh-with-password-authentication

Comment: @MieerDarwesh  You can also use the scripted solution, the one that uses `expect`.

Comment: Nice, i'll check it out!

Answer (score 0):

Do: *export TERM=vt100* **within Mac-OSX** ;export TERM=vt100; ssh xyz@xyz.com. Basically when you ssh from Mac, the client Mac-ssh software decides which terminal settings to use based on the environment variables of your shell and Zyxel doesn't recognize what Mac-OSX is using/asking it to use. Typing vt100 on your Zyxel command prompt is useless since this is negotiated at connection time.

Comment: This did not work, thank you for the effort